# Mottie jQuery Tablesorter fork custom sort only sorting one direction

Tags: jquery, parsing, sorting, fork, tablesorter

I seen an other guy who had the same issue ( [jquery tablesorter ajax table only sorting one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825462/jquery-tablesorter-ajax-table-only-sorting-one-direction) ) but it's not the same cause.

I use a fork of jQuery Tablesorter ( https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter ) to sort a column via a custom parser (French date/time) using a data-attribute :

```
<td data-since="28-09-2012 15:41:10">
    <strong>4 jours, 16 minutes</strong> (28-09-2012 15:41:10)
</td>
```

I can sort ascendantly the column with success but when I try to click again on the column header, the plug-in doesn't sort descendently.

The other columns, with basic data format are correctly sorted in the both directions.

Here is the custom parser, based on the doc and other stackoverflow posts :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550354/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-secondary-hidden-sorting
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'parseSinceColumn',
        is: function(s) {
            return /\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/.test(s);
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            // get data attributes from $(cell).attr('data-something');
            var cellDate = $(cell).attr('data-since');

            s = s.replace(/\-/g," ");
            s = s.replace(/:/g," ");
            s = s.split(" ");

            return new Date(s[2], s[1]-1, s[0], s[3], s[4], s[5]).getTime();
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });
    $("#pr-table").tablesorter({
        headers : {
            3 : { sorter: 'parseSinceColumn' }
        }
    });
});
```

Have you got any idea on the way to fix that?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :

I think the plug-in really try to sort, but the result is the same.

Here is the debug of the plug-in :

- First sort, success :

Sorting on 3,1 and dir 1 time (8ms)

Rebuilt table (3ms)

Completed applying widgets (0ms)

- Second sort, no changement in the sort :

Sorting on 3,0 and dir 0 time (7ms)

Rebuilt table (3ms)

Completed applying widgets (0ms)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.

There was two coarse errors :

- I telling to the plug-in that the index column 3 has the parser 'parseSinceColumn' so the "is" function should return false. In fact, the content of the cell cannot match the regex because 's' is not the content of the data-attribute so the plug-in cannot detect that is the good parser for that column

  - The format function use 's' parameter to parse the date. The good variable is cellDate...

This is the final and fonctional snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550354/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-secondary-hidden-sorting
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'parseSinceColumn',
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            var cellDate = $(cell).attr('data-since');
            // get data attributes from $(cell).attr('data-something');
            // check specific column using cellIndex
            cellDate = cellDate.replace(/\-/g," ");
            cellDate = cellDate.replace(/:/g," ");
            cellDate = cellDate.split(" ");

            return new Date(cellDate[2], cellDate[1]-1, cellDate[0], cellDate[3], cellDate[4], cellDate[5]).getTime();
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });
    $("#pr-table").tablesorter({
        headers : {
            3 : { sorter: 'parseSinceColumn' }
        }
  });
});
```